# Intersection Observer API + Foundation Interchange

Tags: zurb-foundation, intersection, interchange

Using Zurb Foundation framework.  It has a component called Foundation Interchange to serve responsive images.

See https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/interchange.html

While it does serve images based on viewport, it does not support lazy load and we want to lazy load some images using the `Intersection Observer` API.

See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/lazy-loading-guidance/images-and-video/

**Objective:**

When we choose to lazy load something and give an `IMG` the class "lazy", then `Foundation Interchange` serves a low res/small placeholder image.  This part is easy.  Then use `Intersection Observer` to simply change one folder in the path so it then points to the high res image. This is the harder part.

**Important note:**

Most techniques don’t work because we are loading responsive images so I can’t simply point to one image that varies depending on viewport.

We want to apply a class to any image and make it lazy load another image based on `Intersection Observer`.  It will load a low res small image right away and then swap it out for another high res image later on.

Instead of using data-src like most solutions, we want to change the path to the image.

For example, assume the `SRC` is:

```
<img class=”lazy”  src="assets/img1/test-blur2.jpg">
```

I want to have `Observer` watch and change the image path as follows:

```
<img class=”lazy” src="assets/img/test-blur2.jpg">
```

In other words, I want to look for images with `class=lazy` and delete the “1” after /img, and then show the updated image.

Thanks in advance for any tips